# How can I extend PrintWriter?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a class that extends [`java.io.PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html). Because `PrintWriter` doesn't have a no-arguments constructor, I created one, using `super()` to invoke the parent constructor with a path as its argument.

```
public class PlotWriter extends PrintWriter {
    PlotWriter(String path) {
        try {
            super(path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            //Exeption Handled
        } 
    }
}
```

The compiler requires exception handling around `super()`.

But at the same time, it complains:

```
Error:(14, 18) java: call to super must be first statement in constructor
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: Wouldn't it work to replace the try-catch with a throws clause?

Comment: Extract the try catch around the `new PlotWriter` call

Comment: Why would you want to catch this exception in constructor? Decision how to handle it should most likely be made by person who will use that class. For now it looks like [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: *"Because PrintWriter doesn't have a no-arguments constructor"* If you want a no-arg constructor, why are you creating a one-arg constructor? You're not making any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
public class PlotWriter extends PrintWriter {

    PlotWriter(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(path);
    }
}
```

Exceptions should be handled by the caller, they don't intended to be handled in constructor.

```
public void someWhere() {
    try {
        PlotWriter pw = new PlotWriter(".../path/file");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // handle exception here
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the first statement in constructor should always be `super(...);` or `this(...);` (`super();` is called implicitly if you don't specify any of this calls) and they cannot even be both together.

Comment: *"first statement in constructor should **always** be super(...); or this(...)"* Not if you intend to call no-arg constructor (assuming there is one of course).

Comment: It will be called implicitly anyway